sign in with google not working anymore, sign in without google works
I'm a beginner with flutter and started building my app.
My login was functional until very recently, not sure what I changed but now I can't log in with my google account anymore, normal log in works.
Searched a lot but couldn't really find an answer.
login page code
class LoginPage extends StatefulWidget {
  final Function()? onTap;
  final void Function() togglePages; // Adăugați parametrul aici

  const LoginPage({
    super.key,
    required this.onTap,
    required this.togglePages, // Specificați parametrul aici
  });

  @override
  State<LoginPage> createState() => _LoginPageState();
}

class _LoginPageState extends State<LoginPage> {
  final emailController = TextEditingController();
  final passwordController = TextEditingController();

  //logare
  void signUserIn() async {
    showDialog(
      context: context,
      builder: (context) {
        return const Center(
          child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
        );
      },
    );

    try {
      await FirebaseAuth.instance.signInWithEmailAndPassword(
        email: emailController.text,
        password: passwordController.text,
      );

      Navigator.push(
        context,
        MaterialPageRoute(
          builder: (context) => EcranPornire(),
        ),
      );
    } catch (e) {
      print("Registration Error: $e");
      showErrorMessage();
    }
  }

  void showErrorMessage() {
    showDialog(
      context: context,
      builder: (context) {
        return AlertDialog(
          backgroundColor: Colors.blueGrey[100],
          title: const Text("Eroare de autentificare"),
          content: const Text("A aparut o problema. Te rog incearca din nou!"),
          actions: [
            TextButton(
              onPressed: () {
                Navigator.pop(context);
              },
              child: const Text("OK"),
            ),
          ],
        );
      },
    );
  }

auth_page
class AuthPage extends StatelessWidget {
  const AuthPage({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: StreamBuilder<User?>(
        stream: FirebaseAuth.instance.authStateChanges(),
        builder: (context, snapshot) {
          if (snapshot.hasData) {
            return EcranPornire();
          } else {
            return EcranPornire();
          }
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}

auth_service
class AuthService {
  final FirebaseAuth _auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;
  final GoogleSignIn googleSignIn = GoogleSignIn();

  Future<User?> signInWithGoogle() async {
    try {
      final GoogleSignInAccount? googleSignInAccount =
          await googleSignIn.signIn();
      if (googleSignInAccount != null) {
        final GoogleSignInAuthentication googleSignInAuthentication =
            await googleSignInAccount.authentication;
        final AuthCredential credential = GoogleAuthProvider.credential(
          accessToken: googleSignInAuthentication.accessToken,
          idToken: googleSignInAuthentication.idToken,
        );
        final UserCredential authResult =
            await _auth.signInWithCredential(credential);
        return authResult.user;
      }
    } catch (error) {
      print("Error signing in with Google: $error");
      return null;
    }
  }

  Future<void> signOut() async {
    await _auth.signOut();
    await googleSignIn.signOut();
  }
}


I tried updating sha1 key, disabling and enabling Google login again, updating androidmanifest.xml
